# Нужно ли выделять запятыми определение-уточнение в данном примере?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, уточнения, пояснительные

"На следующий, тридцать второй(,) день попала в ловушку и поранилась".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В запятой необходимости нет. ***Тридцать второй*** не уточнение (переход от более общего к частному), а пояснение.

***На следующий, тридцать второй день попала в ловушку и поранилась.***

[**Пояснительные конструкции**](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=119) (Розенталь)

> **Примечания**:
>   2. Определения, носящие характер пояснения (перед ними можно поставить слова *а именно, то есть* и т. п.), отделяются запятой от поясняемого слова, но после них **запятая не ставится**:
>
> *Очередной, **шестой** том подписного издания на днях поступит в магазин; Он заговорил совсем другим, **серьёзным** тоном.*